# Aligning my test samples with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am getting this error when i try to run my simple liner regression sample:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,8) and (1,) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0).
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm


df = pd.read_csv('table.csv') 
print (df.head())



df = df[['Price', 'Asset']]
x = np.array(df.Price)
y = np.array(df.Asset)



x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
x, y, test_size=0.33)

x_train = np.pad(x, [(0,0)], mode='constant')
x_train.reshape((23,1))

y_train = np.pad(y, [(0,0)], mode ='constant')
y_train.reshape((23,1))

x_train = np.arange(23).reshape((23, 1))
x_train = x.reshape((23, 1))
c = x.T
np.all(x_train == c)


clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(clf.coef_)
print(clf.predict(x_test - y_test) **2)
print(clf.score(x_test, y_test))

plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, color='black')
plt.plot(x_test, clf.predict(x_test), color='blue')

plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Asset')

plt.show()
```

I have searched for similar questions and i did not find anything helpful. My test size is 8 samples which is 33% of my population of 23 (the traceback below has a snippet of my population). This is the full traceback of my error message:

```
        Price    Asset
0    87.585859    191
1    87.839996    232
2    87.309998    245
3    88.629997    445
4    88.379997    393
[ 29.67925381]
C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-030ffa933525>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HP/Documents/linear.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Documents')

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HP/Documents/linear.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(clf.predict(x_test - y_test) **2)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 200, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 185, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 184, in safe_sparse_dot
    return fast_dot(a, b)

ValueError: shapes (1,8) and (1,) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Thank you!

Comment: As said by the error the dot product of a `(1,8)` array and a `(1,)` does not make sense. So either you have a serious bug in your code or maybe you are just missing a transpose somewhere so that you actually perform a dot product between a `(8,1)` and a `(1,)` array.

Comment: i am not sure i totally understand but i did reshape my train sample and not my test sample. I have posted my full code above.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print((clf.predict(x_test) - y_test) **2)`?

Comment: Yea...a coming problem, i will fix that. Thanks! Any suggestions on what to do about my sample not aligning?

Comment: reshape the test samples as well...

Comment: @julienbernu Tried reshaping with: 'x_test = np.arange(8).reshape((8,1))
x_test = x.reshape((8,1))
c = x.T
np.all(x == c)' and got the error: 'ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged' or is this meant to be 8,1 and 1,8? Trying to wrap my mind around this.

Comment: you need to use the actual length of your training array instead af `8`! Or use `.reshape((-1,1))` to reshape to automatically detect the correct length required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122796/discussion-between-bolajio-and-julien-bernu).